# What types of testing do you include in your build process?

Tags: testing, build-automation

I use TFS 2008.  We run unit tests as part of our continuous integration build and integration tests nightly.

What other types of testing do you automate and include in your build process?  what technologies do you use to do so?

I'm thinking about smoke tests, performance tests, load tests but don't know how realistic it is to integrate these with Team Build.

Answer (score 3):

First, we have check-in (smoke) tests that must run before code can be checked in. It's done automatically by running a job that runs the tests and then makes the check-in to source control upon successful test completion. Second, cruise control kicks off build and regression tests. The product is built then several sets of integration tests are run. The number of tests vary by where we are in the release cycle. More testing is added late in the cycle during ramp down. Cruise control takes all submissions within a certain time window (12 minutes) so your changes may be built and tested with a small number of others. Third, there's an automated nightly build and tests that are quite extensive. We have load or milestone points every 2 or 3 weeks. At a load point, all automated tests are run plus manual testing is done. Performance testing is also done for each milestone. Performance tests can be kicked off on request but the hardware available is limited so people have to queue up for performance tests. Usually people rely on the load performance tests unless they are making changes specifically to improve performance. Finally, stress tests are also done for each load. These tests are focussed on making sure the product has no memory leaks or anything else that prevents 24/7 running of the product as opposed to performance. All of this is done with ant, cruise control, and Python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating load testing during you build process is a bad idea, just do your normal unit testing to make sure that all your codes work as expected. Load and performance testing should be done separately.